# Winter Bash hats - visibility

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash-2015

I just found this new feature of winter Hats
and got my first one (Sufganiot)

I told about it to a friend, and she said she doesn't see it on my profile.

So my question is:

Are they visible only to the owner, or it should be also visible to others?

Comment: They're visible to others. Be patient. It might be caching.

Comment: Wow dude, that was FAST!

Comment: They need to be logged into Stack Overflow - they don't show up for anonymous users.

Comment: Also, on SO you have to deliberately activate hats.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - can you explain what you meant by : **activate hats**. Perhaps I missed that part.

Comment: As far as I understand, when you wear a hat on a site (not Stack Overflow, e.g. in Cooking) and leave the "only on this site" unticked, it cause the hat to appear on all sites, *except Stack Overflow*. You have to explicitly go to your SO profile and wear a hat there to have it activated

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've found that question (you marked been duplicated from), just after *Wrzlprmft* wrote about the **activate hats**. But I think it should stay, because the previous question is _3 years old_ which might make it NOT up to date. (Perhaps I wrong though)

Comment: Sure your question can stay,  but closed as duplicate. You keep the reputation, future search will become easier. Win win situation. :)

Comment: Got it - thanks ;-) and of course: **Happy hat hunting**

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, putting on a hat "on all sites" automatically counts as saying "I love hats", so it automatically opts you in on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @balpha thanks for the correction, good to know.